# Assign points to an array of week scores in Python

Tags: python, database, loops, sorting

I am buiding a site using Flask with Python 3.8.5. I have an array of scores each representing a week.

```
[
{'GameWeek': 1, 'JH Score': 71, 'Harry Score': 70, 'Alex Score': 64}, 
{'GameWeek': 2, 'JH Score': 80, 'Harry Score': 41, 'Alex Score': 52}, 
{'GameWeek': 3, 'JH Score': 40, 'Harry Score': 60, 'Alex Score': 46}, 
{'GameWeek': 4, 'JH Score': 41, 'Harry Score': 29, 'Alex Score': 65}, 
{'GameWeek': 5, 'JH Score': 65, 'Harry Score': 56, 'Alex Score': 65}, 
{'GameWeek': 6, 'JH Score': 63, 'Harry Score': 54, 'Alex Score': 38}, 
{'GameWeek': 7, 'JH Score': 47, 'Harry Score': 65, 'Alex Score': 46}, 
{'GameWeek': 8, 'JH Score': 87, 'Harry Score': 70, 'Alex Score': 88}
]
```

I need to assign points to each player based on how well they do each week.
If they get the highest score of the week, they get 2 points
If they come second, they get 1
If they come last, they get 0.

I plan to add in that if they draw first place, both get 1.5, and if they draw second place, both get 0.5.

How do I calculate the total points for each player, ideally without hardcoding their names? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: what have you tried? 
Hint: you can just create a new dictionary then loop thru the array and add as keys any field from the gameweek ones that is not "GameWeek"..  and keep track of the points per week and/or total. 
Make sure you handle the case where it is the first time you enter a player's name that was not in previously.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried sorting each week by Value, but I can't then figure out how to assign points without hard coding the name. If you loop through the dictionaries how would you then assign points based on the largest each week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step one is to get the data into an easier format -- a list of `(score, name)` tuples for each week.  All the other stuff can be added back in for UI purposes, but when you're trying to get your data organized it's not useful to have extra strings in there.  While we're generating those lists we can even sort them by score since it'll make the next step easier:

```
>>> data = [
... {'GameWeek': 1, 'JH Score': 71, 'Harry Score': 70, 'Alex Score': 64},
... {'GameWeek': 2, 'JH Score': 80, 'Harry Score': 41, 'Alex Score': 52},
... {'GameWeek': 3, 'JH Score': 40, 'Harry Score': 60, 'Alex Score': 46},
... {'GameWeek': 4, 'JH Score': 41, 'Harry Score': 29, 'Alex Score': 65},
... {'GameWeek': 5, 'JH Score': 65, 'Harry Score': 56, 'Alex Score': 65},
... {'GameWeek': 6, 'JH Score': 63, 'Harry Score': 54, 'Alex Score': 38},
... {'GameWeek': 7, 'JH Score': 47, 'Harry Score': 65, 'Alex Score': 46},
... {'GameWeek': 8, 'JH Score': 87, 'Harry Score': 70, 'Alex Score': 88}
... ]
>>> weekly_scores = [
...     sorted([(v, k[:-6]) for k, v in week.items() if k[-6:] == " Score"], reverse=True)
...     for week in data
... ]
>>> weekly_scores
[[(71, 'JH'), (70, 'Harry'), (64, 'Alex')], [(80, 'JH'), (52, 'Alex'), (41, 'Harry')], [(60, 'Harry'), (46, 'Alex'), (40, 'JH')], [(65, 'Alex'), (41, 'JH'), (29, 'Harry')], [(65, 'JH'), (65, 'Alex'), (56, 'Harry')], [(63, 'JH'), (54, 'Harry'), (38, 'Alex')], [(65, 'Harry'), (47, 'JH'), (46, 'Alex')], [(88, 'Alex'), (87, 'JH'), (70, 'Harry')]]
```

Now we can set up a `defaultdict` to track the total scores for each player:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> total_scores = defaultdict(int)
```

and go through the weekly scores to calculate the totals.  Having the data in the right format (sorted lists of scores) makes it very easy to apply the rules you described:

```
>>> for week in weekly_scores:
...     total_scores[week[0][1]] += (
...         2 if week[0][0] > week[1][0]
...         else 1.5
...     )
...     total_scores[week[1][1]] += (
...         1.5 if week[0][0] == week[1][0]
...         else 1 if week[1][0] > week[2][0]
...         else 0.5
...     )
...     total_scores[week[2][1]] += (
...         0.5 if week[1][0] == week[2][0]
...         else 0
...     )
...
>>> total_scores
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'JH': 10.5, 'Harry': 6, 'Alex': 7.5})
```

Note that there are some edge cases -- what if there are fewer than three scores?  What if there's a three-way tie?  I'll leave you to determine how to handle those since your description doesn't cover them.  :)

If you want to make the code that calculates the total scores a little more readable (it's hard to keep track of all the levels of indirection between the list and the tuples IMO) at the expense of writing a little more code, I'd personally use a `NamedTuple` to make it so I can say `.score` instead of `[0]` and `.player` instead of `[1]`:

```
>>> from typing import NamedTuple
>>> class ScoreEntry(NamedTuple):
...     score: int
...     player: str
...
>>> weekly_scores = [
...     sorted([
...         ScoreEntry(v, k[:-6]) for k, v in week.items() if k[-6:] == " Score"
...     ], key=lambda entry: entry.score, reverse=True)
...     for week in data
... ]
>>> total_scores = defaultdict(int)
>>> for week in weekly_scores:
...     total_scores[week[0].player] += (
...         2 if week[0].score > week[1].score
...         else 1.5
...     )
...     total_scores[week[1].player] += (
...         1.5 if week[0].score == week[1].score
...         else 1 if week[1].score > week[2].score
...         else 0.5
...     )
...     total_scores[week[2].player] += (
...         0.5 if week[1].score == week[2].score
...         else 0
...     )
...
>>> total_scores
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'JH': 10.5, 'Harry': 6, 'Alex': 7.5})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this is wonderful! Greatly appreciated indeed. Fairly new to python so there are methods here that it's great to be exposed to, thank you again.